# Making a mesh model from a point cloud: What are the plans for the model_mesher from the tod_training package?

Tags: ros, model, tod-training, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We got the tod_training package working, according to the [BaseCreation tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tod_training/Tutorials/BaseCreation).  I noticed a program called "model_mesher," whose code looks like it is supposed to output a ".ply" (mesh) file from a bag file with a point cloud as input.  Unfortunately, there were assertion errors:

/tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-perception-pcl-0.10.0/debian/ros-diamondback-perception-pcl/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/perception_pcl/flann/include/flann/algorithms/kdtree_single_index.h:151: void flann::KDTreeSingleIndex::BoundingBox::computeFromData(const flann::Matrix&) [with Distance = flann::L2_Simple]: Assertion `data.rows>0' failed.

I am assuming this is still under development, since it was updated very recently.  It doesn't look like it is being used in the OpenCV [solutions in perception challenge](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/http%3A/opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/SolutionsInPerceptionChallenge).  What are the plans for the model_mesher program?  Is it still under active development?  Should we try to improve it ourselves?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9714/making-a-mesh-model-from-a-point-cloud:-what-are-the-plans-for-the-model_mesher-from-the-tod_training-package?/) by [sdavies](https://answers.ros.org/users/406/sdavies/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2011-04-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This model_mesher is not supported anymore and we will soon have a cleaner/more organized version of it (by July/August 2011).

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2014-06-16**:
I know toooooooooo old a link, but is there anything like model mesher available as of now?